# How to pre-filter to a minimum number of rows per group before resampling without double-resampling?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a mock of my actual use-case, suppose I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(1, 32), 
                  columns=['a'], 
                  index=pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2021-01-31'))
```

I'd like to pre-filter resampling groups to a minimum number of X rows before applying a function. I could find the number of rows per resampling group as follows:

```
df.resample('W').apply(lambda x: x.shape[0])
>              a
> 2021-01-03   3
> 2021-01-10   7
> 2021-01-17   7
> 2021-01-24   7
> 2021-01-31   7
```

In that example above I would like to run my resampling excluding or filtering out the subgroup corresponding to date `2021-01-03` because it only has 3 rows, periods or days.

The desired output is, for example, taking mean, it should exclude the case of `2021-01-03` BUT before applying the actual function, not after:

```
df.resample('W').filter_here_to_min_7_rows().apply(lambda x: x.mean())
>                 a
> 2021-01-10      7
> 2021-01-17      14
> 2021-01-24      21
> 2021-01-31      28
```

**UPDATE** More context, why do I need this? in my real use-case the apply function is much more complex and if the minimum number of rows is not satisfied, I need to handle a border case providing an empty result which impacts the aggregated resampling type result. Therefore I'd prefer to have the apply function getting correct input groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also reuse [`Resampler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/resampling.html)/[`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html) objects:

```
g = df.resample('W')['a']
g.mean()[g.count().ge(7)]
```

output:

```
2021-01-10     7.0
2021-01-17    14.0
2021-01-24    21.0
2021-01-31    28.0
Freq: W-SUN, Name: a, dtype: float64
```

###### only computing the aggregation function when the group matches a criterion

If your goal is to avoid computation of the mean (or any other potentially computation expensive aggregation) in case the group does not match a condition, you could use `apply`:

```
df.resample('W')['a'].apply(lambda x: x.mean() if x.count()>=7 else None).dropna()
```

*NB. In case of `mean` on this dataset this will likely be slower, especially since here you expect small groups (max. 7 days), but this might be better for other aggregation functions or very large groups.*

Comment: thanks @jezrael , I was about to add a link ;)

Comment: thanks a lot @mozway, but this filters the data after the mean, I would like the mean to run on the pre-filtered data ...

Comment: @SkyWalker check the update, but be aware that in the current case this might be slower than filtering after

Comment: Thanks a lot @mozway, this is what I am doing right now in my real-life use-case but causes trouble for me because depending on whether I hit the filtering case the result of the computation is cast as a different output type between pd.DataFrame and pd.Series, this is why I'd like to filter out those _before_ doing my apply function.

Comment: I suggest you open a new question with a reproducible minimal example of your real-life process and show how this fails in the edge cases you describe. It might be better to handle those directly ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with a callable to filter the aggregated rows:

```
df.resample('W')['a'].agg(['count', 'mean']).loc[lambda df: df['count'] >= 7, 'mean']
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but this runs the filter after the mean, I would like the mean to run on the pre-filtered data ...

Answer (score 3):

Another option, using [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.pipe.html):

```py
df.resample(on='W').a.pipe(lambda g: g.mean()[g.size() >= 7])
 
2021-01-10     7.0
2021-01-17    14.0
2021-01-24    21.0
2021-01-31    28.0
Freq: W-SUN, Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but this runs the filter after the mean, I would like the mean to run on the pre-filtered data ...